# how to send a unique message with MQTT?

Tags: java, mqtt

i need your help. I am creating a program with MQTT, it must execute commands written on a file and send the result to a topic. I have already managed to execute the command and print the result on the terminal, but when I have to send it via MQTT it creates two messages, is it possible to send a message only with the result? how can I do? thanks I'll put the code for reading the result of the command executed and the two messages it sends me.

```
String result;
while ((result=reader.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(result);
  final  MqttTopic timeTopic = client.getTopic(TOPIC);
  timeTopic.publish(new MqttMessage(result.getBytes()));
  System.out.println(" - Published data. Topic: " + timeTopic.getName() + "  Message: " + result);
}
```

[image: message]

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is a line at a time, if the command outputs multiple lines then you are going to send multiple messages.

You need to loop over the output from `reader.readLine()` store all the results and then publish the message.

```
String line;
String output = "";
while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
  output += line + "\n";
}
final MqttTopic timeTopic = client.getTopic(TOPIC);
timeTopic.publish(new MqttMessage(line.getBytes()));
System.out.println(" - Published data. Topic: " + timeTopic.getName() + "  Message: " + result);
```